# Single Sign on with different modules

Tags: cakephp, authentication, single-sign-on, access-token

I have 
1. web application
2. API Layer that runs OAuth Server
3. Report Server
4. Mobile App that use web app APIs and API from API server
5. some different modules as well

I am using CAKEPHP in backend
Now Here my question starts.
What would be the best way of maintaining Authentication across the system.

Currently I am using an action written on API Server that generates token and client id. that I saved locally in web app and I use for subsequent request.

now I have problem with maintaining Session
Ques 1 : Do I need to maintain single session based on access token
or multiple session maintain by user id.

Ques 2. Do I need to assign same token per user with different device or different access token every time user login with different device.

Ques 3. How can I secure access token like if someone intercept access token he/she shoudn't be able to access data.

So many confusion and question.
Can anyone guide me with best approach handling all users, session, token and different devices.

Thank you in Advance.